# How to no identing the first line with paracol + verse

Tags: indentation, paracol, verse

How can I get the first verse of poems without indentation? As you can see in my MWE, I successfully changed the left margin for every verse, except the first one in the first column.

I tried `\hspace` and `\noindent` but they did not work!

```
\documentclass[
paper=a5,
fontsize=10pt,
DIV=calc,
headsepline,
footsepline,
titlepage,
headings=normal,
version=last,
%twoside=true,           % prova eliminazione geometry
headinclude=true,
footinclude=true,
mpinclude=true,
BCOR=1.8cm % spazio rilegatura
]{scrbook}
\usepackage[
left=1.5cm,
right=1.5cm,
top=1cm,
bottom=1cm,
includeheadfoot
]{geometry}


\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{paracol}
\footnotelayout{m}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} % Required for colour specification
\newcommand{\nomelistapoesie}{Lista delle poesie}
\newlistof{poesia}{top}{\nomelistapoesie}
\newcommand{\poesia}[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{poesia}
    \addcontentsline{top}{poesia}
    {\protect\numberline{\thepoesia}#1}
}

\newcommand*{\plogo}{\fbox{$\mathcal{PL}$}} % Generic dummy publisher logo

\deftripstyle{pagestyle}
[0.5pt]
[0.3pt]
{\pagemark}
{}
{\titleinfo}
{\pagemark}
{\authorinfo}
{}

\pagestyle{pagestyle}
\renewcommand{\chapterpagestyle}{pagestyle}

\newcommand{\titleinfo}{S\u{u}ahila Metriko}
\newcommand{\authorinfo}{Nino Vessella, 1980}

\newlength{\saveleftmargini}
\newcommand\poezio[2]
{\setcolumnwidth{0.5\linewidth,0.5\linewidth}
    \begin{sloppypar}
    \setlength{\saveleftmargini}{\leftmargini}
    \setlength{\leftmargini}{0em}% for example to outdent verse

    \begin{paracol}{2}
        \begin{verse}
            \textbf{#1}
        \end{verse}
        \switchcolumn
        \begin{verse}
            \textit{#2}
        \end{verse}
    \end{paracol}

    \setlength{\leftmargini}{\saveleftmargini}% restore original value  
    \end{sloppypar}
}


\begin{document}
Description of the first poem:%
\poezio{\poesia{Simba ndume wa wambuji, sikizani tatongoa}
   {\textcolor{Red}{Simba ndume}} na wambu\underline{ji}, sikizani tatongo\underline{a}!\\
    Niketele vitongo\underline{ji} na safari za mashu\underline{a}.\\
    Leo nakumbuka mbi\underline{ji} ya kutweka na kutu\underline{a}.\\
    Ai, pato na mpe\underline{wa}! Litakapo kukuta\underline{na}!\\
    \ldots\footnote{Citita en Bertoncini (1968) kaj en Hichens (1962), p. 115.}
}{
    Fortuloj kaj beluli\underline{noj}, a\u{u}skultu je mia di\underline{ro}!\\
    Mi lo\^{g}is kun  vila\^{g}a\underline{noj} kaj \^{s}ipe sur marlazu\underline{ro},\\
    memoras mi pri have\underline{noj}, dan\^{g}ero kaj maldan\^{g}e\underline{ro}.\\
    Ho, favorat' kaj favo\underline{ro}! \^{C}u iam vi renkonti\underline{\^{g}os}?\\
}

Discussion about the poem.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\parindent=0` unindent all paragraphs in the environment!
I need to remove it only from the first paragraph.

Comment: Actually, it turns out that `\parindent` has no effect on verse.

Answer (score 1):

There was no indentation.  `\posia` was adding several spaces at the start of the first line.

```
\documentclass[
paper=a5,
fontsize=10pt,
DIV=calc,
headsepline,
footsepline,
titlepage,
headings=normal,
version=last,
%twoside=true,           % prova eliminazione geometry
headinclude=true,
footinclude=true,
mpinclude=true,
BCOR=1.8cm % spazio rilegatura
]{scrbook}
\usepackage[
left=1.5cm,
right=1.5cm,
top=1cm,
bottom=1cm,
includeheadfoot
]{geometry}


\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{paracol}
\footnotelayout{m}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} % Required for colour specification
\newcommand{\nomelistapoesie}{Lista delle poesie}
\newlistof{poesia}{top}{\nomelistapoesie}
\newcommand{\poesia}[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{poesia}%
    \addcontentsline{top}{poesia}%
    {\protect\numberline{\thepoesia}#1}%
\ignorespaces}

\newcommand*{\plogo}{\fbox{$\mathcal{PL}$}} % Generic dummy publisher logo

\deftripstyle{pagestyle}
[0.5pt]
[0.3pt]
{\pagemark}
{}
{\titleinfo}
{\pagemark}
{\authorinfo}
{}

\pagestyle{pagestyle}
\renewcommand{\chapterpagestyle}{pagestyle}

\newcommand{\titleinfo}{S\u{u}ahila Metriko}
\newcommand{\authorinfo}{Nino Vessella, 1980}

\newlength{\saveleftmargini}
\newcommand\poezio[2]
{\setcolumnwidth{\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth-0.5\columnsep}% second column takes remaining space, -\columnsep
    \begin{sloppypar}%
    \begin{paracol}{2}
      \setlength{\leftmargini}{0em}% will revert at end of paracol
        \begin{verse}
            \textbf{#1}
        \end{verse}
        \switchcolumn
        \begin{verse}
            \textit{#2}
        \end{verse}
    \end{paracol}
    \end{sloppypar}
}


\begin{document}
Description of the first poem:%
\poezio{\poesia{Simba ndume wa wambuji, sikizani tatongoa}%
    \textcolor{Red}{Simba ndume} na wambu\underline{ji}, sikizani tatongo\underline{a}!\\
    Niketele vitongo\underline{ji} na safari za mashu\underline{a}.\\
    Leo nakumbuka mbi\underline{ji} ya kutweka na kutu\underline{a}.\\
    Ai, pato na mpe\underline{wa}! Litakapo kukuta\underline{na}!\\
    \ldots\footnote{Citita en Bertoncini (1968) kaj en Hichens (1962), p. 115.}
}{
    Fortuloj kaj beluli\underline{noj}, a\u{u}skultu je mia di\underline{ro}!\\
    Mi lo\^{g}is kun  vila\^{g}a\underline{noj} kaj \^{s}ipe sur marlazu\underline{ro},\\
    memoras mi pri have\underline{noj}, dan\^{g}ero kaj maldan\^{g}e\underline{ro}.\\
    Ho, favorat' kaj favo\underline{ro}! \^{C}u iam vi renkonti\underline{\^{g}os}?\\
}

Discussion about the poem.
\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/690261/183677 I don't understand what's happening! If I compile the MWE with your modification I get what I looking for, but when I do the same in my complete file I get the identation at the first verse! Any idea?

Comment: Is poesia defined more than once?  Do you have any other custom macros inside verse?

Comment: `poesia` is defined only once and I don't have any other macros inside `verse`. But I found the "bug"! I had to put the poems immediately after the `\poezio{` instead on the following line! So now every thing is OK without using `\parindent`!